# DLL is generated for 32 bits but fails if generate the same in 64 bits - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++

I do have a program that works and compiles my dll perfectly in 32bits / Windows 7 but fails to generate the dll for 64 bits. All code regeneration is separated in different folders. Also, there is no libraries that I have developed myself that are required to link to this program that are mixed. The ones related to Windows itself seems to be different too.

Any suggestion of what is the cause of this problem ?

The output results is below.

Regards..

```
1>     Creating library D:\Lib\LepComDll\x64\Release\LEPCOM.lib and object D:\Lib\LepComDll\x64\Release\LEPCOM.exp
1>LEPCOM.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __stdcall LepComClose(void)" (?LepComClose@@YGHXZ)
1>LEPCOM.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall LepComDebug(int)" (?LepComDebug@@YGXH@Z)
1>LEPCOM.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall LepComDumpRx(void)" (?LepComDumpRx@@YGXXZ)
1>LEPCOM.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __stdcall LepComGet1Wire(int,int,char *)" (?LepComGet1Wire@@YGHHHPAD@Z)
1>LEPCOM.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __stdcall LepComGetAccel(int)" (?LepComGetAccel@@YGHH@Z)
1>LEPCOM.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "double __stdcall LepComGetDLLVersion(void)" (?LepComGetDLLVersion@@YGNXZ)
1>LEPCOM.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __stdcall LepComGetIds(class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > > *)" (?LepComGetIds@@YGHPAV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z)
```

Comment: All the libs u link to when u create your library must be 64 bits too

Comment: How do I check that. All libs I have programed are compiling together. The only ones I can think are not are basic windows libs such as MFC, ATL and others.. I am not sure how to change that or even see who are they.. Suggestions ?

Comment: Check whatever library or object file `LepComClose` and friends are supposed to be defined in.

Comment: They are defined at my lepcom.def.. see a piece below..Do i need to change that for 64 bits ?;                                          LEPCOM.def : Declares the module parameters for the DLL.
; Copy the prototying from the LEPCOM.MAP file.

LIBRARY      "LEPCOM"
DESCRIPTION  'LEPCOM Windows Dynamic Link Library'

EXPORTS
    ; Explicit exports can go here
 
 LepComGetDLLVersion=?LepComGetDLLVersion@@YGNXZ
 LepComOpen=   ?LepComOpen@@YGHXZ         
 ; CAN Functions
 LepComSendCAN=  ?LepComSendCAN@@YGHHHHH@Z   
 LepComSetIndex=  ?LepComSetIndex@@YGHHHH@Z

Comment: I just fix the problem.  I have removed the .def file and asked the compiler to generate the code and worked. It seems the .def is only required for the 32 bits version.

Answer (score 0):

I just fix the problem. I have removed the .def file and asked the compiler to generate the code and worked. It seems the .def is only required for the 32 bits version.

Comment: `.def` files are perfectly valid for 64-bit DLL builds. Removing it may have had the side effect of doing a clean rebuild, but it shouldn't be the actual solution.

Comment: Any suggestion in how to do it properly ? I might be missing something at the .def or some other parameter. This an old lib created back in 1999. Open to suggestions.